# Create infinite list in Haskell with IO

Tags: haskell

EDITED!

I am trying to write an algorithm that generates an (infinite) list of Mersenne prime numbers. I have an algorithm (Rabin-Miller) that returns an IO Bool, according to whether the algorithm thinks the number is prime or not. This algoritm is called rabinMiller, and it takes two arguments, the first an Integer that says something about the security of the list, and second the number that we're submitting to the primality test.

I want to index over the list of all primes (called primes), and for each p in primes, check whether rabinMiller thinks 2^p - 1 is prime. If it is, we submit 2^p - 1 to the list.

What I have now is this:

```
rbMersenneGen :: Integer -> IO(IO [Integer])
rbMersenneGen k = do return $ rbMersenneGens 0 k

rbMersenneGens :: Int -> Integer -> IO [Integer]
rbMersenneGens x k = 
  let n = primes!!x
      m = (2^n) - 1
  in do
   prim <- rabinMiller k m
    if prim then 
        m:rbMersenneGens (x + 1) k 
    else 
        rbMersenneGens (x + 1) k
```

But this is not really working, since I cannot get the type of `m:rbMersenneGens (x + 1) k` right. I get the error that `m` is an `Integer` instead of an `[Integer]`, and then the type of the entire `m:rbMersenneGens (x + 1) k` is wrong and creates other errors

Comment: You have to do: `if prim then do xs <- rbMersenneGens (x+1) k; return m : xs` to match the types.

Comment: The problem is that Rabin-Miller uses random numbers. Haskell has a problem with random numbers because they are intrinsically impure. If it is your implementation of Rabin-Miller then you need to rewrite it to take the random seed as an argument. Or else use a different primality test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original types are fine; we just need to adjust the definition of `rbMersenneGens` a little. I'm going to refactor the function a little as well.

```
rbMersenneGen :: Integer -> IO [Integer]
rbMersenneGen k = rbMersenneGens 0 k

rbMersenneGens :: Int -> Integer -> IO [Integer]
rbMersenneGens x k = 
  let n = primes!!x
      m = (2^n) - 1
  in do
       prim <- rabinMiller k m
       -- We call rmMersenneGens the same way in either case;
       -- the only difference is which function we apply to the result
       (if prim then (m:) else id) (rbMersenneGens (x+1) k)
```

Your problem is that `prim` needs to be a `Bool` for the `if-else` expression, and the `do` expression needs to evaluate to an `IO [Integer]` value. This means `rabinMiller` would need to return an `[Bool]` value instead of the `IO Bool` that it does. The fix is to replace the `if` else with `Data.Bool.bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a`.

This doesn't type check...

```
rbMersenneGens :: Int -> Integer -> IO [Integer]
rbMersenneGens x k = 
  let n = primes!!x
      m = (2^n) - 1
      prim = rabinMiller k m -- IO Bool
  in (bool id (m:) prim) (rbMersenneGens (x+1) k)
```

because we are still trying to treat `prim` as a `Bool` rather than an `IO Bool`, but this does:

```
rbMersenneGens :: Int -> Integer -> IO [Integer]
rbMersenneGens x k = 
  let n = primes!!x
      m = (2^n) - 1
      prim = rabinMiller k m
  in (bool id (m:)) <$> prim <*> (rbMersenneGens (x+1) k)
```

We can't make `if` work with an `IO Bool`, but we *can* lift `bool` to work with one. In fact, we only need to treat `IO` as an `Applicative`, not a `Monad`. We are replacing `>>=` with `fmap` (in its infix form `<$>`).

Comment: Won't that loop forever (IO being a strict applicative)?

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Only `(m:)` and `id` need to be switched (in the last row), since `bool` behaves weird. And if I run `rbMersenneGen k` it never returns something... But I can solve this by making `rbMersenneGens n _ = return []` for some n

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the description of `bool` closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have a do block in `rbMersenneGens`. The result of a do block is always in the same monad as the things inside. Since you call `rabinMiller` inside, which is in the `IO` monad, the result of the do block is in the `IO` monad as well. Yet you have declared that `rbMersenneGens` returns a `[Integer]`, which doesn't match the deduced type.

Comment: Yep. I think OP may be falling into [this common trap](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/1904/io/7236/getting-the-a-out-of-io-a#t=201610051636053171053)

Comment: But if i let it return `[IO Integer]` and `rbMersenneGen` `IO [IO Integer]` the same error occurs (and two more)

Comment: The declared return value means the `do` expression is operating in the list monad, and `prim` needs to be a `Bool` since it is used with the `if` expression. This means `rabinMiller` would need to return a `[Bool]` value, but it returns an `IO Bool`.

Comment: @Mal The return type of `rbMersenneGens` should be `IO [Integer]`, I think.

Comment: So I changed the type of `rbMersenneGen` to `IO (IO [Integer])` and the type of `rbMersenneGens` to `IO [Integer]`, but my compiler is not really a fan of the expression `m:rbMergenneGens (x+1) k`, since it wants `m` to be an `[Integer]` instead of `Integer` (and then two errors that it expects `IO [Integer]` but it is actually `[[Integer]]` and then the other way around..)

Comment: @Mal You cannot just throw types at the compiler until it shuts up. You need to understand what the `IO Bool` result type of `rabinMiller` (and `IO` in general) means.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, throwing types at the compiler until it shuts up is the best approach I've found thus far for working with non-regular data types using polymorphic recursion. Of course, that probably just means my brain isn't strong enough.